# systemd: recover from systemctl hang

Tags: service, systemd, systemctl

I have a custom systemd ".service" file, like this one:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyStuff
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
After=local-fs.target
After=remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/MyStuff/start
ExecReload=/bin/kill $MAINPID && /usr/bin/cat /var/run/MyStuff.pid | /usr/bin/xargs --no-run-if-empty /bin/kill
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID && /usr/bin/cat /var/run/MyStuff.pid | /usr/bin/xargs --no-run-if-empty /bin/kill
ExecStartPost=/usr/local/MyStuff/after_start.sh
PIDFile=/var/run/MyStuff.pid
#RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=300
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It worked fine until minutes ago. A `systemctl stop MyStuff` hung this way:

```
[root@Live-1 ffmpeg]# systemctl status WowzaStreamingEngine
● MyStuff.service - MyStuff
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/MyStuff.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (final-sigkill) (Result: timeout) since vie 2017-07-28 11:12:23 -03; 23min ago
Main PID: 25149
CGroup: /system.slice/MyStuff.service

jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "/usr/bin/cat"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "/var/run/MyStuff.pid"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "|"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "/usr/bin/xargs"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "--no-run-if-empty"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 kill[10382]: kill: cannot find process "/bin/kill"
jul 28 11:12:23 Live-1 systemd[1]: MyStuff.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
jul 28 11:17:24 Live-1 systemd[1]: MyStuff.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
jul 28 11:22:24 Live-1 systemd[1]: MyStuff.service still around after SIGKILL. Ignoring.
jul 28 11:31:22 Live-1 systemd[1]: MyStuff.service stop-final-sigterm timed out. Killing.
```

I know there are errors reported there. That is not the problem; I'm not asking about those errors. The problem is: **systemd/systemctl hangs in that state, and i'm unable to do start/stop/restart actions because all of them stays waiting forever**.

What i need to know is a way around that state. This time I just rebooted the server, because it was development environment. But i can't just deal this way on production.

So: **when systemd/systemctl hangs this way, what can I do in order to recover my service from this state without rebooting the server?**

Thanks in advance.